# sql query chokes the server

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query mysql server cpu usages stays at 100% and chokes the server. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects p, orders o, invoices i
WHERE p.project_state =  'product'
AND (
p.status =  'expired'
OR p.status =  'finished'
OR p.status =  'open'
)
AND p.user_id =  '12'
AND i.projectid =0
GROUP BY i.invoiceid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Check the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM...` and post it. That group by will run across the entire table even with the LIMIT, and your other fields may not be indexed. You could also make the `AND (p.status` better by writing `P.status IN ('expired', 'finished', 'open')`

Comment: This is the output from EXPLAIN:

id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE i ref projectid projectid 4 const 255 Using temporary; Using filesort

1 SIMPLE p ALL status,project_state NULL NULL NULL 745 Using where

1 SIMPLE o ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 156

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are including the orders table but not joining to it. This will make a full cross join that can potentially produce millions of rows.

Comment: +1 they need to have a `WHERE p.projectID = o.projectID AND o.orderID = i.orderID` or very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXPLAIN` to find out the query plan. From that you can work out what indexes will be required. Those indexes will vastly improve performance.

Also you are not limiting the orders in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put any joins on the tables.  I believe by default that will do a cross join.  That means if you have 1000 projects, 100,000 orders and 100,000 invoices the resultset will be 1,000,000,000,000 (1 trillion) records.

You probably want to put some inner joins between those tables.